# I'm looking for a word that matches a financial concept

Tags: single-word-requests, finance

I'm looking for a word that I'm not sure exists (disclaimer: English is not my first language).

The foreign exchange market deals with currencies e.g. USD, EUR, etc.
The stock market e.g. NASDAQ deals with public companies' stock, e.g. AAPL.

There are markets, and there are the *entities* that are traded in those markets.

What's the generic name of these *entities*, so I could say:

> AAPL is a ________ in NASDAQ
>
> Gold is a ________ in the metals market
>
> USD is a ________ in the currency market

etc...

Comment: there were several comments to this questions, and were wiped out. Why?